# How do I fix RN suddenly being unable to find local modules (Unable to resolve module)?

Tags: react-native

I've got a strange situation where suddenly my RN app won't load any of its scenes. The app has been running fine for weeks and I haven't moved any of the files. The failure:

```
error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `./src/scenes/splash` from `/Users/jcollum/projects/starsApp/index.ios.js`: Directory /Users/jcollum/projects/starsApp/src/scenes/splash doesn't exist
at Promise.resolve.then (/Users/jcollum/projects/starsApp/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:445:15)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

My import statements look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import Splash from './src/scenes/splash';
```

The scene definitely exists:

```
$ ll /Users/jcollum/projects/starsApp/src/scenes/splash.js 
-rw-r--r--  1 jcollum  staff   722B Apr 26 10:12 /Users/jcollum/projects/starsApp/src/scenes/splash.js
```

And it has an `export default`:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles'
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

export default class Splash extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Actions.Home()
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(`rendering Splash`);
    return (
      <View ...
```

Things I have tried:

- restarting packager
- resetting content and settings
- checking out a previous commit
- clearing temp dir: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*`

`react-native --version`

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.43.2
```

What could be causing this? Why would this suddenly stop loading resources? What's the next thing to try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution (don't know why this works, sorry):

1. Stop any running packager
2. Add this to package.json: `"clean-start": "rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react* && npm start --reset-cache",` (or npm install if you don't use yarn)
3. `npm run clean-start`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, ran

```
npm cache verify
```

in console at my project directory, all was well. Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue once and what i did was nothing fancy, I just cut all the files which were giving error and copied at some place(outside my project dir) and then paste those files again at their place helped me..

Cheers :)

Comment: Lol this is actually what worked me after trying everything above and multiple stack overflows