# Unable to resolve module prop-types, but grep prop-types reveals nothing

Tags: react-native

I got sources for an ios app dropped (from end 2016) in my lap, and am now trying to build and run it in the simulator. I am just learning React Native.

Full error message is here:

```
Unable to resolve module prop-types from /Users/raarts/work/MobileApp/app/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
  /Users/raarts/work/MobileApp/app/node_modules/react-redux/node_modules
,   /Users/raarts/work/MobileApp/app/node_modules

This might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968
To resolve try the following:
  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.

RCTFatal
-[RCTBatchedBridge stopLoadingWithError:]
__25-[RCTBatchedBridge start]_block_invoke_2
_dispatch_call_block_and_release
_dispatch_client_callout
_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
__CFRunLoopRun
CFRunLoopRunSpecific
GSEventRunModal
UIApplicationMain
main
start
```

Of course I did try the suggested solution, but that didn't work.
My problem is: I inspected Provider.js, but the word 'prop-types' does not even occur in that file.

Here's the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint index*.js src __tests__",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "google-libphonenumber": "^2.0.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.40.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^0.7.1",
    "react-native-debug-stylesheet": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.9.7",
    "react-native-i18n": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.2.8",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.36.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-send-intent": "^1.0.13",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-actions": "^0.12.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^3.12.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.2.1",
    "fetch-mock": "^5.6.0",
    "jest": "18.1.0",
    "jest-react-native": "16.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

I googled around, and it seems prop-types was split off into a separate package as a replacement for PropTypes which became deprecated with React 15.5. So my initial guess was that some dependent package was using `prop-types`. But imagine my surprise when I grepped the entire node_modules tree for 'prop-types' and it wasn't mentioned anywhere (accept in the changelog for eslint-plugin-react).

So now I'm baffled. What is happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered my question: [How do I fix RN suddenly being unable to find local modules (Unable to resolve module)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43727464/how-do-i-fix-rn-suddenly-being-unable-to-find-local-modules-unable-to-resolve-m?rq=1)

Turns out the advice given in the error actually *was* correct, but I missed an error message.

Answer (score 6):

**you need prop-types module.**

```
 npm install --save prop-types
```

Comment: @vahdet
prop-types module not installed in your app , that why this error showing. if you install and re run then it will resolve your issue.